# Bind with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

When using `bind()` on an Event Listener in JavaScript I can no longer get the element with "this".

Here is my code:

```
function callback(){

     console.log(this.someVar);
     // Works fine

     console.log(this);
     // No longer refers to the element, outputs "Object"

}

callback = callback.bind({someVar: 1234});

element.addEventListener('click', callback);
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: That is what `bind` does - it sets the `this` context permanently. If you don't want this behaviour, then perhaps you shouldn't use `bind`.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: @VLAZ what can I use as an alternative?

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan "Object"

Comment: @Ood what is your goal here? Why do you use `.bind`? Because the alternative is to simply not use it.

Comment: I will write an answer now.

Comment: @VLAZ I want to pass a variable to the function in the event but this variable is constantly changing. When the event fires I want the function to output the value of the variable from the time the EventListener was created.

Comment: do you mean `element.addEventListener('click', callback);` ?

Comment: Is the variable an object or a primitive?

Comment: However, I also need to know the element of "this".

Comment: @VLAZ The variable is an integer as in the example.

Comment: @lazyboy Yes, thanks for the correction. I made an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass one variable but keep the `this` context, then you can use currying or partial application:

## [Curry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying)

Your function has to receive a value and return another function. This way you can do the following:

```js
function callback(num) {
  return function() {
    console.log(num);
    console.log(this.id);
  }
}

var number = 1;

document.getElementById("hello").addEventListener("click", callback(number));

//change the variable
number = 2;
document.getElementById("world").addEventListener("click", callback(number));

//change the variable again
number = 3;
```

```html
<button id="hello">Hello</button>
<button id="world">World</button>
```

## [Partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)

Same idea but instead of having your callback return a new function, it will just take a single argument and work normally, you need another function that will do the partial application:

```js
function callback(num) {
  console.log(num);
  console.log(this.id);
}

var number = 1;

document.getElementById("hello").addEventListener("click", partial(callback, number));

//change the variable
number = 2;
document.getElementById("world").addEventListener("click", partial(callback, number));

//change the variable again
number = 3;


function partial(fn, arg) {
  return function() {
    return fn.call(this, arg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="hello">Hello</button>
<button id="world">World</button>
```

The partial application function can be generalised to handle any amount or arguments

In ES6:

```js
function partial(fn, ...args) {
  return function(...otherArgs) {
    return fn.apply(this, [...args, ...otherArgs]);
  }
}
```

In ES5:

```js
function partial(fn) {
  var args = [].prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    var otherArgs = [].[].prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return fn.apply(this, args.concat(otherArgs));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value.

So, when you call a function like

`callback = callback.bind({someVar:1234})`

`this` inside the function callback will be the object `{someVar:1234}`

To access `someVar` in the callback function, you have to use `this.someVar`.

I hope this helps.

If you are still unclear refer this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

---

You can still use event.target and can get access to the clicked element.

```
function callback(event){

 console.log(this.someVar);
 // Works fine

 console.log(event.target);
 // No longer refers to the element, outputs "Object"

}

callback = callback.bind({someVar: 1234});

element.addEventListener('click', callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call bind() only once. After bind() called, `this` reference is bind to the argument. So the even can not be assigned to `this`. For example:

```
function f() {return this;}
f = f.bind({a:1});
f(); // => {a:1}
f = f.bind({a:2}); // this is what addEventListener actually do as if it bind this to even
f(); // {a:1}
```

addEventListener cannot bind this again.

Comment: You can call `bind` multiple times. Even if you call it on a bound function, you can perform partial application.

Comment: I means in context of `callback = callback.bind({someVar: 1234});`